# How to use minimum_should_match to search in multiple fields with multiple search terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new at elasticsearch so if it's a simple question please forgive me.

I have lets say 6 keywords and i want to search these in multiple fields and get documents if at least 4 of them in every documents. In addition to that i may want to separate 1 of them and say this must be in the document. How should it be implemented?

I'm doing half of these with minimum_should_match but i want to broaden it with both multiple field and with a must one.

Comment: so basically out of 6, 1 must be present and min 3 should be matched out of rest 5 keywords?

Comment: yes that is a good summary :)

Comment: can you please show what have you tried so far?